# Input tipo fecha con formato ingles

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, format

Tengo un input de tipo date el problema es que por defecto este viene con el formado

dd/mm/yyyy

Pero la empresa para la que trabajo es americana, y necesita las fechas en un formato ingles, es decir

mm/dd//yyyy

aqui el detalle, el proyecto esta basicamente terminado, solo falta este detalle y existen muchos de estos campos por todo el sistema, ¿Existe alguna forma de darle un formato ingles?

Estoy usando bootstrap como framework css, no se si sea reelevante.

Comment: Deberias agregar algo de codigo.

Comment: Y donde estas mostrando esa fecha. en html? o en otro lado?

Comment: El `<input type="date">` basa el formato de la fecha en la configuración local del usuario ([Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#sect1)). En su defecto, puedes usar el *widget* [datepicker()](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), de jQuery, con el cual puedes [manipular el formato de la fecha mostrada](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Comment: Como dice @Alexis88 puedes usar datepicker o si no quieres usar y son registros ya guardados y mostrarás, puedes simplemente usar *split* de Javascript y ordenas como necesites

Comment: alexis le sabe. ya quedó